# Android: Mail and Browser links opening my app | IntentFilter Problem

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have an app running on top of React Native and Expo.

There I have set the settings in app.json to open my app for certain domains:

```
"intentFilters": [
            {
                "action": "VIEW",
                "autoVerify": true,
                "data": [
                    {"scheme": "https","host": "www.meet4ride.de","pathPrefix": "/touren"},
                    {"scheme": "https","host": "www.meet4ride.de","pathPrefix": "/forum"},
                    {"scheme": "https","host": "www.meet4ride.de","pathPrefix": "/members"},
                    {"scheme": "https", "host": "app.meet4ride.de","pathPrefix": "/touren"},
                    {"scheme": "https", "host": "app.meet4ride.de","pathPrefix": "/forum"},
                    {"scheme": "https", "host": "app.meet4ride.de","pathPrefix": "/members"},
                    {"scheme": "m4r", "pathPrefix": "/touren"},
                    {"scheme": "m4r", "pathPrefix": "/forum"},
                    {"scheme": "m4r", "pathPrefix": "/members"}

                ],
                "category": ["DEFAULT", "BROWSABLE"]
            }
          ]
```

**For some (not all) Android users, it ends up in my app when clicking on links in the email program or in the normal browser. The link itself doesn't matter for now, since it's the case for all links.
Anyone have any idea what this may be related to?**